# iPad mini offers update to iOS 6.0.2 that won't install

Tags: ipad, software-update

An update to iOS 6.0.2 did not seem so important at the time and so it was never installed. Now that iOS 6.1 is out I'd expect that Software Update skips the update to iOS 6.0.2 and directly provides me with the ability to update from iOS 6.0.1 to iOS 6.1 instead.

And yet, Software Update is stuck with the intention to update to iOS 6.0.2. In the hope that after iOS 6.0.2 was successfully installed Software Update  may offer to install iOS 6.1 next I accepted the update to iOS 6.0.2.

However, the next thing is that Software Update claims that the installation of iOS 6.0.2 cannot be started because there is no connection to the Internet. I positively verified that the connection is possible; so the most likely explanation is that Software Update is not able to find the update to iOS 6.0.2 any longer and concludes that this is caused by a lack of connectivity.

How can I make Software Update ignore the pending update to iOS 6.0.2 and head for iOS 6.1 instead?

Comment: Update through iTunes. You may have to use the restore option. And if you do, make a backup beforehand.

Comment: What if the iPad has (who could blame it) never seen iTunes in its life so far? I guess it is still worth a try.

Comment: Same thing happening with my iPhone 5, however I did download 6.0.2 several weeks ago, just never installed it. Now it's unable to verify the update (via wifi or LTE). I guess I'll try the restore from backup (incidentally, I too have never connected my phone to iTunes).

Comment: @UweHonekamp Worst case, you would need to erase the iPad and lose some content. With an iCloud backup, though you could skip backing up to iTunes and just use iTunes to wipe / restore it to factory clean iOS 6.1 condition and unplug it. Then you could restore from iCloud. Just double check all content you care is backed up to iCloud :) An untethered "erase all content and settings" might also do the trick to clear the update - but again requiring some backup so you don't lose content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since things aren't working as expected, make a backup - perhaps two, one to iTunes and another to iCloud.

Connect the device to iTunes and let iTunes download the entire 6.1 update rather than monkeying with a pair of delta patches that iOS downloads to save space on the device and save bandwidth and time to update.

Comment: Confirmed, update works according to this answer. Thanks for the proposal.